# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68

Tags: c, xcode

I am new to coding and am trying a practice problem for Input.txt
I've copied the code exactly how my instructor has it in the lecture, but am getting this error message next to my fscanf line. I'm using TextEdit for my input.txt file and have the file stored in the same folder as my program. I'm also using XCode.

```
// Pre- Processor Directives
#include <stdio.h>

// Main Function
int main(void) {
    // Input File Pointer
    FILE * ifp; 

    // Variable Declaration and Initialization
    int i, header, cur_val, sum=0;

    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &header);

    // For Statement
    for(i=0; i<header; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &cur_val);
        sum += cur_val;
    }

    // Print Results
    printf("The sum of the numbers in the file is %d.\n", sum);

    // Close the file
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Check the return value from `fopen`.  Your attempt to open the file may have failed, e.g. if the file is not in the current directory, or the current directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: Address 0x68 is only 104 bytes above address 0, it means that `fopen` **did** return NULL, and `fscanf` is trying to address some byte in the structure `*(FILE *)0`.